# Filtering rows within a date range using nggrid in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am a newbie in ANgularJS.Now I am working with ng-grid.I have two date pickers.First one for from date and the second one for to date.And I have a column which contains the dates itself. I want to filter rows within the date range.Is there any way to do this?Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am using some dummy data in the ng-grid now.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/kBcUIayO8tQsTTjTA2vO?p=preview  This is the plunker I am referring.Actually there is no way to link with columndefs in ng-grid

Comment: There is no ng-grid and no dates in your example...